# How can I remove the default host header for SSL requests in IIS6

Tags: ssl, https, iis-6, host-headers

I have multiple sites setup on IIS 6 with host headers.  One of those sites has an SSL certificate installed.  So now if any of the non-SSL-enabled sites is requested with HTTPS it loads the SSL-enabled site and gives a security warning.

How can I prevent the non-SSL sites from loading anything if they are requested with https?  I would prefer it to throw the standard "Server not found" message.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to achieve this with IIS 6 is to put the SSL-enabled site onto its own IP address and set IIS up not to listen on port 443 of the main IP address.

In SSL (without [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) - not yet supported by IIS), the client validates the server's certificate before it sends the requested hostname to the server. The server has to choose a certificate to send based on just the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

No true.

Use header host for ssl and only specify for the SSL enabled site th correct host header.

cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set /w3svc//SecureBindings ":443:www.yourcustomer.com"